# Realm accessed from incorrect thread when try to view pdf file again Swift 3

Tags: swift, realm, alamofire

i have collection view and user can tap to download pdf file. If download complete, it shows the pdf file. But after pdf showed up and go back then tap the cell again to show the pdf again, it throws `Realm accessed from incorrect thread.`

Here's my code to download file:

```
func downloadData(_ magazineObject: Magazine, cell: magazineCell) {
Alamofire.download(magazineObject.urlMagazine, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, to: destination)
        .downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { progress in
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.percentProgressFinal = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)

                magazineObject.progressBarDownload = progress.fractionCompleted.roundToPlaces(places: 2)
                magazineObject.progressBarTitle = Float(self.displayFinalLabelPercent).cleanValue

            }
        }
        .validate { request, response, temporaryURL, destinationURL in
            self.localPath = destinationURL
            magazineObject.pathDatabase = String(describing: self.localPath!)
            magazineObject.progressBarDownload = Double(self.percentProgressFinal)
            magazineObject.progressBarTitle = Float(self.displayFinalLabelPercent).cleanValue
            magazineObject.statusDarkViewAfterRelaunch = 1

                let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc:PDFKBasicPDFViewer = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NEXT") as! PDFKBasicPDFViewer
                let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
                let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(magazineObject.title).pdf"

                let document: PDFKDocument = PDFKDocument(contentsOfFile: filePath, password: nil)
                vc.loadDocument(document)

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

            magazineObject.statusDownload = self.statusDatabase

            let realm = try! Realm()

            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(magazineObject)
            }

            return .success
    }
}
```

and show the file if already downloaded:

```
if statusGlobal {
        if magazineObject.statusDownload == 0 {
            magazineObject.statusDownload = 1

            //Alamofire Request
            downloadData(magazineObject, cell: cell)

            cell.progressDownload.isHidden = false
            cell.progressLabel.isHidden = false

        } else {
            let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc:PDFKBasicPDFViewer = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NEXT") as! PDFKBasicPDFViewer
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(magazineObject.title).pdf"
            let document: PDFKDocument = PDFKDocument(contentsOfFile: filePath, password: nil)
            vc.loadDocument(document)

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

but if i re-run the simulator, it can show my pdf file.

Comment: Is the code you provided above the _only_ place you ever get a `Realm` and use it?

Comment: yes it's the only place I get a Realm and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by creating another variables

```
 let newMagazineObject = Magazine()
            newMagazineObject.id = magazineObject.id
            newMagazineObject.pathDatabase = magazineObject.pathDatabase
            newMagazineObject.progressBarDownload = magazineObject.progressBarDownload
            newMagazineObject.progressBarTitle = magazineObject.progressBarTitle
            newMagazineObject.statusDarkViewAfterRelaunch = magazineObject.statusDarkViewAfterRelaunch
            newMagazineObject.statusDownload = magazineObject.statusDownload

            let realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(newMagazineObject)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xcode's exception breakpoints](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) to set a breakpoint on C++ exceptions being thrown, then look up the stack trace of where the "incorrect thread" exception is thrown to see which line of your code is triggering the exception. From there, you should be able to determine which Realm object you're incorrectly sharing across threads.